# MongoDB Atlas Function inconsistent behaviour between HTTPS call and debug run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, https, find, mongodb-atlas

Using postman to make a https request returns an error, whilst the function runs in the debugger.

*This is best explained with screen grabs of the issue*

Runs in the mongodb function editor: [working function editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46LXs.png)

Fails by postman request (http endpoint set to respond with result):
[postman request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ktS.png)

Additionally .toArray() method causes this failure, which is annoyingly nondescript!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: as the flexible sync queryable field was in the users custom data, this must be made available to the function with a toggle in the http endpoint settings